# Converting a string to double for coordinate use, Xcode

Tags: objective-c, string, double, coordinates

I have a list of longitudes and latitudes in an XML file. I can print the lat and lon as a string but when i convert the string to a double i get 0.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *latstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:theList.lat] ;
NSString *lonstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:theList.lon];
NSLog(@"latstring: %@, lonstring: %@", latstring, lonstring);

double latdouble = [latstring doubleValue];
double londouble = [lonstring doubleValue];
NSLog(@"latdouble: %g, londouble: %g", latdouble, londouble);
```

When i log 'latstring' and 'lonstring'  i get the correct coordinates however when i log 'latdouble' and 'londouble' i get 0.

I need the lat and lon values as double so i can use them in a mapview as it will not allow me to use a string for the coordinates.

There is probably a very simple explanation for this however i am fairly new to objective-c and cant seem to find a solution for this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"latstring: %@, lonstring: %@", latstring, lonstring);` actually display?

Comment: The console displays:  2012-07-25 12:10:28.720 XMLTest2[4851:707] latstring: 
55.035966, lonstring: 
-1.710799
2012-07-25 12:10:28.721 XMLTest2[4851:707] latdouble: 0, londouble: 0

Comment: The conversion and formatting are certainly OK.  For example, `NSLog(@"lat: %g, lon: %g", [@"55.035966" doubleValue], [@"-1.710799" doubleValue]);` works fine (excluding rounding).  Try logging the length of the strings just before the double conversion to see if there are any non-printable characters causing trouble.

Comment: When i log the length:                                                                NSLog(@"latstring length: %i, lonstring length: %i", latstring.length, lonstring.length);                                                         I get:                                                                     'latstring length: 10, lonstring length: 10'

Comment: Is that correct?  I can't tell whether there's supposed to be leading whitespace (which should be OK) or some other extra character.

Comment: No i think there should only be 9 characters. My xml file looks like this:                                                                    <Taxi>
<name>Airport Taxis</name>
<number>01912146969</number>
<address>Newcastle International Airport, Woolsington, Newcastle</address>
<lat>55.035966</lat>
<lon>-1.710799</lon>
</Taxi>
Could the problem lie here? I tried creating the lat and lon properties of 'theList' as double rather than string however i still  end up with zero when i log them.

Comment: It could be XML content and it could be something about how values are put into `theList`.  It's hard to tell by looking at what's printed; you may need to track the data with the debugger or examine the individual characters that are being put into `theList.lat` (for example).

Comment: A tip for debugging: When printing out strings you are trying to check the value of try wrapping them in markers so you are sure which characters come from them and which come from the debugger text. for example NSLog(@"Coords as strings are (%@,%@)",theList.lat,theList.lon);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved the issue. After counting the length of the strings like Phillip said to do it turned out the length was 1 character longer than the string. So i added another string in-between that was the same string as 'latstring' and 'lonstring' however it began at index 1 rather than 0, therefore cutting off whatever character must have been infront of the coordinate value. This then converted to double perfectly.

Here is the code is used:

```
NSString *latstring = theList.lat;
NSString *lonstring = theList.lon;
NSLog(@"%@, %@ wooo", latstring, lonstring);

NSString *latcutstring = [latstring substringFromIndex:1];
NSLog(@"cut lat: %@", latcutstring);
NSString *loncutstring = [lonstring substringFromIndex:1];
NSLog(@"cut lon: %@", loncutstring);

double latdouble = [latcutstring doubleValue];
NSLog(@"latdouble: %f", latdouble);
double londouble = [loncutstring doubleValue];
NSLog(@"londouble: %f", londouble);
```

Thankyou Phillip Mills and Tobol for you're help.

EDIT: Nov 2012

It was white space causing problems and i have found a safer way of doing this as to not cut out needed characters, as craig and phillip said.

```
NSString *trimlat = [theList.lat stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *trimlon = [theList.lon stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    //Convert to double
    double latdouble = [trimlat doubleValue];
    double londouble = [trimlon doubleValue];

    //Create coordinate
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {(latdouble),(londouble)};
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I would be nervous, though, about clipping the first character without knowing why it was there.  Since it comes from an unknown cause, there's no guarantee that next time it won't be 0 or 2 characters.

Comment: Yeh i know what you mean i have tried to trace back the data but am struggling to find out what the extra character is. I have gone through every location in my xml file and they all show up on the mapview in the correct place. It works ok for this project however it may not work in others as you say there may be a different number of characters. But for now it will do.

Comment: I agree with Phillip, cutting of an arbitrary number of characters without knowing why could mean you're not going to be handle anything new. So you're in the UK and you've got double digit positive latitudes and single digit longitudes (I'm guessing you've tried positive and negative ones). But what about the US where they have triple digit negative longitudes, you could be cutting off the vital negative sign which would move all their points to China. The XML you gave only has 9 characters but you're receiving 10 that means your XML extraction needs work. Fix that and all coords should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think those strings aren't formatter well. there can't be anything else than whitespace before the number. The lat and lon has to be in format like as 'dd.ddddddd'.

```
    NSString *works = @"  12.5431 jdty";
    NSString *doesntWorks = @"E 43.4345";
    NSString *latstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:works] ;
    NSString *lonstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:doesntWorks];
    NSLog(@"latstring: %@, lonstring: %@", latstring, lonstring);

    double latdouble = [latstring doubleValue];
    double londouble = [lonstring doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"latdouble: %g, londouble: %g", latdouble, londouble);
```